# VOIP/IM Server most secure software

Tags: open-source, server, voip, debian

I want to make a VOIP /IM server in Debain .What is the most secure software i can use? It will be used by a couple of people and running 24/7.

- can be in beta or alpha
- should have really good encyption such as AES 256 bit or better
- no backdoors
- open-source
- Audio only
- 2 people maybe 3
- log in required
- no resource limit
- There will be no file sharing over IM
- Open id or anyother protocols

Comment: How do you define "most secure"? Some metric, gut feeling?

Comment: Secure as in really good encyption such as AES 256 bit or better encyption with no backdoors and open source.

Comment: That encryption then also needs to be supported by the clients. What protocol(s) must be supported? Is "audio-only" sufficient, or do you need video (and text-typing) facilities? Conferencing? Speaking of "IM": file exchange (and if yes, malware check for those files)? Link evaluation (e.g. verifying shortened links)? Are there any resource limits (RAM/disk/CPU)? How many users? What about registration: should everyone just be able to use it, or do you need account management included? If so: SSO required, and again which protocols (e.g. OpenID) for that?

Comment: Combining requirements *most secure* and *can be in beta or alpha* sounds a bit strange...

Comment: True but I dont think there is alot of software out there that meets my requirments.

Comment: Wasn't **"Debain"** the villain in one of the Batman movies?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to stick with the well known standards sip, srtp and zrtp have a look at [Ostel](https://ostel.co/) or to be more concrete [OSTN](https://dev.guardianproject.info/projects/ostn/wiki/Wiki) from the [Guardian Project](https://guardianproject.info/apps/ostel/).

for a "closed environment/user-base" [Mumble](https://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Main_Page) (with its server [Murmur](https://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Running_Murmur)) can be interesting.

---

well... or you can take a look at "new" projects in early stages like [Tox](https://tox.chat/) (NaCl-encryption) or [Ring](https://ring.cx/) (because of dht without a central server), but i won't recommend them for production environments because the are under (heavy) development!